# Concatenating two columns in Oracle giving performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a select query where I am doing inner joins and in `AND` clause I am checking like this

```
AND UPPER (b.a1||b.a2)  IN 
(
    select a.a1||a.a2 
    from a 
    where a.a3 = 
    (
        select  UPPER(decode('609',null,c.c1,'609'))   
        from dual
    )
)
```

but so because of `||` opertaor it is taking more than 2 minutes. Can we have any other solution to this?

Comment: What is the table b? It the same as table a? Do you have indexes on b.a1, b.a2 and a.a1,a.a2?

Comment: Create a function based index `CREATE INDEX  somename ON table_b_name( upper(a1||a2) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `EXISTS` clause?

```
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        a
    WHERE
        a.a3 = (SELECT UPPER(DECODE('609',c.c1,'609')) FROM dual) -- this condition is pretty odd
        AND a.a1 = UPPER(b.a1)
        AND a.a2 = UPPER(b.a2)
)
```

Adding Function Based Indexes on UPPER(b.a1) AND UPPER(b.a2) may help as well.

Speaking of that odd condition: `(SELECT UPPER(DECODE('609',c.c1,'609')) FROM dual)`:

1. Why do you perform a `SELECT` from dual there?
2. What you check is - if `'609'` equals `c.c1` (`'609'`) then `a.a3` must equal `'609'`, in any other case your `SELECT` returns `NULL`, thus no value from table `a` is returned. So you can just change the entire condition to `a.a3 = '609'`.

Comment: As I will be passing '609' as parameter. So if user did not pass anything it will return c.c1 not null ... whereas I can directly use decode also ...Thanks for solution it is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a `JOIN`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM b
 JOIN ( select UPPER(a.a1), UPPER(a.a2)
        from a 
        where a.a3 = (select  UPPER(decode('609',c.c1,'609')) from dual)
      ) a
    ON UPPER(b.b1) = a.a1
   AND UPPER(b.b2) = a.a2
```

But the problem is when you do `UPPER(b.b1)` or `b1||b2` you cant use the index anymore.

You may need a [function index](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes#concatenated-columns)

Comment: I think you are assuming that `a.a3` is unique (at least for value 609)  If that assumption proves false, your advice to convert `IN` to `JOIN` will cause the rows from table `b` to be duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to concatenate. In fact: concatenating the values is a bug waiting to happen: consider the the values `foob` and `ar` in table `b` and `foo` and `bar` in `a` - the concatenation treats those as the same tuple although they are not.

You also don't need the `select from dual` for a constant:

```
AND (UPPER (b.a1), upper(b.a2))  IN 
(
    select a.a1. a.a2 
    from a 
    where a.a3 = UPPER(decode('609',null,c.c1,'609'))   
)
```

An index on `b(a1,a2)` can't be used for this, but you can create an index on `b (UPPER (b.a1), upper(b.a2))` which would be used.